# Scripting Errors?

Tags: add-on

I'm trying to make a Perforce Addon, I saw a few people asking for it. It will be free to the public of course. I am having issues figuring python out. I have spent about two days researching and looking for different methods. From what I can tell I am doing it all the recommended way. Can someone look at my code and tell me where I messed up?

I was going to just expose it here but it looks funny so I am making a pastebin.

[Perforce Plugin Code](https://pastebin.com/2mQMWRfu)

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####

#Addon Information
bl_info = {
    "name": "Perforce Tools",
    "author": "PlacidStorm",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "blender": (2, 7, 8),
    "location": "View3D > Tools > Perforce Tools",
    "description": "Adds some tools for improve the Blender to Perforce workflow",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Perforce Tools"}

#Import Information.
import bpy
import os

class PerforceServerProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    Server_IP = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="Server_IP",
        description="Server IP",
        default='192.168.0.1')
    Server_Port = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="Server_Port",
        description="Server Port",
        default='1666')
    Server_Login = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="Login Name",
        description="Your Server Login Name",
        default='')
    Server_Pass = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="Password",
        description="Your Server Password",
        default='')

# Class for the Tool Panel.
class PerforceToolPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Perforce Tools"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = 'Perforce Tools'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        filename = bpy.path.basename(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath)

        layout.label(text="Perforce Server Info", icon='WORLD_DATA')
        layout.label(text="File Info", icon='FILE_BLEND')
        layout.label(text="Current File: " + filename)



# Class Registration
classes = [
    PerforceServerProperties,
    PerforceToolPanel

    ]

def register():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)

def unregister():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)

bpy.types.Scene.serv_prop_grp = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=PerforceServerProperties)
# Needed to run script in text editor
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Add 4 spaces to the start of each line and paste to get a code block. Most source code editors will add the spaces if you select the text and press tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a custom [property](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html) to the scene, you need to place the property creation line inside the `register()` function, and then delete it in `unregister()`

```
def register():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)
    bpy.types.Scene.serv_prop_grp = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=PerforceServerProperties)

def unregister():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)
    del bpy.types.Scene.serv_prop_grp
```

Other than variable declarations, without any functions used to initialize them, you can't have any code outside of function or class definitions in a blender addon.

Comment: Thanks, I was so close to figuring this out. I am not use to using Python. I usually use C#. I did a edit and other than the unregister part. All I was missing was the tab/4space assigning the serv_prop_grp.